# PHP Upload Video

Tags: php, video, file-upload

I have been trying to upload an image and video and update data at the same time, I can upload the image, but it wont upload when I am also uploading a video and the data gets updated but my video will not upload. I've been trying to get the video to upload for weeks with no success... This is what I've tried:

I've tried adding MIME Types to my `.htaccess` file

```
AddType video/avi .avi
AddType video/quicktime .mov
AddType video/mpeg .mpeg .mpg
AddType video/mp4 .mp4
```

and I've tried changing my phpinfo settings in my php5.ini file

```
max_execution_time = 3000
upload_max_filesize = 50MB
```

Here is the PHP upload code

```
if (($_FILES["image"]["type"] == "image/jpeg") || ($_FILES["image"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")){
            if ($_FILES["image"]["error"] > 0){
                echo $_FILES["image"]["error"];
            }else{
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"],
                "../upload/video_1_" . date("Ymd") . $_FILES["image"]["name"]);
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["video"]["tmp_name"],
                "../upload/video_2_" . date("Ymd") . $_FILES["video"]["name"]);     
                $class->update($id, $title, $description, $image, $video);
                echo "<div style='padding-left:50px'><strong>Updated!</strong></div>";
            }
        }else{
            echo "<div style='padding-left:50px'><strong>Invalid Image!</strong></div>";
        }
```

I ran a `print_r` on `$_FILES` and it returned an empty array

My Video size is 40.9MB

Any help or a point in the right direction would be appreciated, 
Thanks in advanced,
J

This is my form

```
<form action="Videos.php?action=updatesubmit" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $array['id']; ?>" name="id" />
<p>
<label for="name" style="vertical-align:top;">Title</label>
<input type="text" name="title" id="title" value="<?php echo $array['title']; ?>" />
</p>
<p>
<label for="description" style="vertical-align:top;">Description</label>
<textarea name="description" id="description" cols="70" rows="20"><?php echo $array['description']; ?></textarea>
</p>
<p>
<label for="image">Image</label>
<input type="file" name="image" id="image" value="<?php echo $array['image']; ?>" />
</p>
<p>
<label for="video">Video</label>
<input type="file" name="video" id="video" value="<?php echo $array['video']; ?>" />
</p>

<p>
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Update" />
</p>

</form>
```

Comment: MIME types have nothing to do with uploads.

Comment: what does your form look like? If $_FILES is empty then its likely you've forgotten the `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Comment: I have updated my question to include the form, I had the enctype="multipart/form-data"

Comment: You may also want to check `post_max_size` in you php.ini ...

Comment: For uploading large files i would suggest you to use jquery plugin http://www.uploadify.com/demos/

Answer (score 0):

If `$_FILES` is empty and you're not getting an error message when you upload, chances are you forgot to set `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in the `<form>` tag.

Comment: Updated my question with the form, I had that part :(

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at web server error_log and access_log to see what happens. Is the file actually uploaded or not.